# Temp Table - Temporary table is empty - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I know this question I'm about to ask is quite common, but I haven't been able to use other examples to my own.

I have a stored procedure that uses a table `Enum_Tables` (this table has other table names) to search the entire database for a specific string. The results are stored in a table which gives me the specific rows of `Enum_Tables` that I want.

Currently the stored is working properly, but right now it is creating SearchTMP in the Database. And I don't want that, What I want is creating a temporary table like #SearchTMP. I created the temporary table, I tried to populated it, but It is empty.

The part I'm talking about is inside the while logic (WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @SQLTbl WHERE ISNULL(Execstatus ,0) = 0) ).

It's checking if there is values in SearchTMP, and since it's not a temporary table, it's creating one in the database. I want to change it to a #SearchTMP. I I created the table, but I'm not being able to populated it, since I wan't being able to do it, I deleted that code. I know I need to do an insert, but how can I do it without changing to much code, and maintain the same logic.

This is my stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchTables_TEST] 
    --@Tablenames VARCHAR(500)
    @SearchStr NVARCHAR(60),
    @GenerateSQLOnly Bit = 0,
    @SchemaNames VARCHAR(500) ='%' 
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    DECLARE @MatchFound BIT 
    SELECT @MatchFound = 0 

    DECLARE @CheckTableNames Table (Schemaname sysname, Tablename sysname) 
    DECLARE @SearchStringTbl TABLE (SearchString VARCHAR(500)) 

    DECLARE @SQLTbl TABLE (Tablename SYSNAME, 
                           WHEREClause VARCHAR(MAX),
                           SQLStatement VARCHAR(MAX),
                           Execstatus BIT  
                          )

    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @TableParamSQL VARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @SchemaParamSQL VARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @TblSQL VARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @tmpTblname sysname 
    DECLARE @ErrMsg VARCHAR(100)    

    IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@SchemaNames)) ='' 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @SchemaNames = '%' 
    END 

    --IF CHARINDEX(',',@Tablenames) > 0  
    --    SELECT @TableParamSQL = 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE(@Tablenames,',','''as TblName UNION SELECT ''') + '''' 
    --ELSE 
    --    SELECT @TableParamSQL = 'SELECT ''' + @Tablenames + ''' as TblName ' 

    IF CHARINDEX(',',@SchemaNames) > 0  
        SELECT @SchemaParamSQL = 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE(@SchemaNames,',','''as SchemaName UNION SELECT ''') + '''' 
    ELSE 
        SELECT @SchemaParamSQL = 'SELECT ''' + @SchemaNames + ''' as SchemaName '  

    SELECT @TblSQL = 'SELECT SCh.NAME,T.NAME 
              FROM SYS.TABLES T 
              JOIN SYS.SCHEMAS SCh 
              ON SCh.SCHEMA_ID = T.SCHEMA_ID 
              INNER JOIN [DynaForms].[dbo].[Enums_Tables] et on 
                 (et.Id = T.NAME COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)  '


    INSERT INTO @CheckTableNames 
    (Schemaname,Tablename) 
    EXEC(@TblSQL) 


IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @CheckTableNames) 
BEGIN 

    SELECT @ErrMsg = 'No tables are found in this database ' + DB_NAME() + ' for the specified filter' 
    PRINT @ErrMsg 
    RETURN 

END 


IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchStr)) ='' 
BEGIN 

    SELECT @ErrMsg = 'Please specify the search string in @SearchStr Parameter' 
    PRINT @ErrMsg 
    RETURN 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN  
    SELECT @SearchStr = REPLACE(@SearchStr,',,,',',#DOUBLECOMMA#') 
    SELECT @SearchStr = REPLACE(@SearchStr,',,','#DOUBLECOMMA#') 

    SELECT @SearchStr = REPLACE(@SearchStr,'''','''''') 

    SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE(@SearchStr,',','''as SearchString UNION SELECT ''') + '''' 



    INSERT INTO @SearchStringTbl 
    (SearchString) 
    EXEC(@SQL) 

    UPDATE @SearchStringTbl 
       SET SearchString = REPLACE(SearchString ,'#DOUBLECOMMA#',',') 
END 



INSERT INTO @SQLTbl 
( Tablename,WHEREClause) 
SELECT QUOTENAME(SCh.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(ST.NAME), 
        ( 
            SELECT '[' + SC.Name + ']' + ' LIKE ''' + REPLACE(SearchSTR.SearchString,'''','''''') + ''' OR ' + CHAR(10) 
              FROM SYS.columns SC 
              JOIN SYS.types STy 
                ON STy.system_type_id = SC.system_type_id 
               AND STy.user_type_id =SC.user_type_id 
              CROSS JOIN @SearchStringTbl SearchSTR 
             WHERE STY.name in ('varchar','char','nvarchar','nchar','text') 
               AND SC.object_id = ST.object_id 
             ORDER BY SC.name 
            FOR XML PATH('') 
        ) 
  FROM  SYS.tables ST 
  JOIN @CheckTableNames chktbls 
    ON chktbls.Tablename = ST.name  
  JOIN SYS.schemas SCh 
    ON ST.schema_id = SCh.schema_id 
   AND Sch.name        = chktbls.Schemaname 
 WHERE ST.name <> 'SearchTMP'
  GROUP BY ST.object_id, QUOTENAME(SCh.name) + '.' +  QUOTENAME(ST.NAME) ; 




  UPDATE @SQLTbl SET SQLStatement = 'SELECT * INTO SearchTMP FROM ' + Tablename + ' WHERE ' + substring(WHEREClause,1,len(WHEREClause)-5) -- this line was uncomment


  DELETE FROM @SQLTbl 
   WHERE WHEREClause IS NULL 

 DECLARE @output TABLE (Id VARCHAR(50), Name VARCHAR(100)) 
 Create Table #SearchTMP (searchparameter varchar(200))


WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @SQLTbl WHERE ISNULL(Execstatus ,0) = 0) 
BEGIN 


    SELECT TOP 1 @tmpTblname = Tablename , @SQL = SQLStatement 
      FROM @SQLTbl  
     WHERE ISNULL(Execstatus ,0) = 0 

     IF @GenerateSQLOnly = 0 
     BEGIN 

        IF OBJECT_ID('SearchTMP','U') IS NOT NULL -- this line was uncomment
        DROP TABLE SearchTMP   -- this line was uncomment


        EXEC (@SQL) 


        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SearchTMP)
        BEGIN 
            --SELECT parsename(@tmpTblname,1) FROM SearchTMP 
            SELECT @MatchFound = 1 

            INSERT INTO @output (Id, Name)
            Select * from [DynaForms].[dbo].[Enums_Tables] where id in (SELECT parsename(@tmpTblname,1) FROM SearchTMP) 
        END 

     END 
     ELSE 
     BEGIN 
         PRINT REPLICATE('-',100) 
         PRINT @tmpTblname 
         PRINT REPLICATE('-',100) 
         PRINT replace(@SQL,'INTO SearchTMP','') 
     END 

     UPDATE @SQLTbl 
        SET Execstatus = 1 
      WHERE Tablename = @tmpTblname 

END 

SELECT * FROM @output

IF @MatchFound = 0  
BEGIN 
    SELECT @ErrMsg = 'No Matches are found in this database ' + DB_NAME() + ' for the specified filter' 
    PRINT @ErrMsg 
    RETURN 
END 

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Comment: Just to point out, those aren't Temporary Tables you're using in the query. They're Table Variables. They two are very different.

Comment: Is this procedure really searching every single column of every single table of every single schema? Do you call this regularly? I am confused about your concern of using temp tables and multiple users. Each user would have their own connection which means they have their own instance of your temp table. But still...the performance of this could get extremely bad if you have very many table in your Enum_Tables.

Comment: I don't really see any inserts into `#SearchTMP`.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, this procedure is really searching every single column, the problem is since enum_tables has the table names, and i need to get specific rows of enum_tables, base on the values of the other tables, I need to search in the entire database. I know the performance is extremely bad, but the client asked me to do this. Besides, the temporary table is meant to bypass a problem in the application. I have several users with the same connection, and the same user, so a temp table should solve this (I hope), since searchtmp is being created in the database.

Comment: You definitely do not have multiple users sharing a single database connection. Temp tables are scoped to a single session. Which means you can multiple connections open at a time. For example, in SSMS each tab is a different session so a temp created in one tab is not available in another. And you can have the same named temp table in each tab and there is no chance either can see the other one.

Comment: @Pred That's the thing, I tried to insert using an select into, but the table keeps getting empty. Since I wasn't able to do it, i deleted from the stored procedure.

Comment: What do you mean "the tables keeps getting empty"? You don't insert (or even declare) the temp table in the code you posted.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm trying to do that, but I can't seem to create the temporary table using the same logic it was previously. Previously, in where #SearchTMP is at now, It was SearchTMP, and it was working, but when multiple users were using it, it kept saying table SearchTMP already exists. Because it is creating the table in the database, and i don't want that. With that in mind, I decided to use a temp table, but I can't replicate the logic.

Comment: Your issue is not at all clear. What do you mean you can't replicate the logic? Change the table variable to a temp table. Pretty simple, change @ to #.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm sorry, I'm not able to explain properly, What I want is, instead in creating a  table SearchTMP in the database, I want to create a temp table. With that in mind, I want to replace SearchTMP to #SearchTMP But i'm not be able to do it. I know this is simple, maybe, I'm not seeing it. I created the table (it's in the code -  Create Table #SearchTMP (searchparameter varchar(200))), but since i wasn't able to populated it with the same logic i was using in SearchTMP.  Again I apologize if i'm not being able to explain properly and again, I thank you for your patience.

Comment: You are not trying to explain the issue you are facing. Why can't you replace SearchTMP with #SearchTMP? And why can't you populate it? Put yourself in my shoes and read what you are posting. You are not providing the details needed to help you here.

Comment: @SeanLange Ok then, in order to help you help me. Thank you again for your patience. What are you understanding right now with my question? So I can change it, in order to others and you understand it.

Comment: You said you want to use a temp table instead of a persistent table. This makes sense so that you don't have concurrency issues and this seems like the right approach. But you stated that you don't know how to populate the temp table like you populate the persistent table. But in the code posted you do not attempt to populate either of them. Where is the code that populates that table now? And why can't you simply change that code?

Comment: @SeanLange I change how question was made, I hope you can understand more. And It seems you understood my problem before I made the edit. I also change the stored procedure  and the way it is now, It works properly, it gives me the data I want but it creates the table in the database. This means, it populates the table. (This stored procedure is not originally mine and I'm changing it according to my needs). The problem is, I need to replicate the same logic to the temptable.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use a temp table in a dynamic query, you have to create said temp table first, then populate it in the dynamic query.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable (ID INT NOT NULL);
DECLARE @STMT NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'INSERT INTO #MyTempTable (ID) SELECT ID FROM MyTable;';

EXEC sp_executesql
  @stmt = @STMT
;

SELECT ID FROM #MyTempTable;
```

Since the temp table is created in the stored procedure, it is scoped to that stored procedure and will be dropped automatically when the SP finishes.

If you want to use said temp table outside of the SP, you have to create it outside of the SP. (If it is part of the batch, the temp table will be dropped when the connection is closed or you can drop it explicitly).